# How to find all values of $a$ such that $y(t) = a/t$ is a solution to $y'' = y^3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all values of the constant $a$ such that $y(t) = a/t$ is a solution to $y'' = y^3$.

Should this be solved as a non-homogeneous equation? I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: Did you compute $y''$ and compare it with $y^3 = a^3/t^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$y(t)=\frac{a}{t}$$ and we get for the derivatives: $$y'(t)=-\frac{a}{t^2}$$ and $$y''(t)=\frac{2a}{t^3}$$ plugging this in your equation we get
$$\frac{2a}{t^3}=\frac{a^3}{t^3}$$ thus we get $$a^3-2a=0$$ or $$a(a^2-2)=0$$ and we obtain $$a=0$$ or $$a=\pm \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: the answer is good, but has it to be a column vector post ?